# How to run query on session end?

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-management, coldfusion-2016

I have query that should run on session end. If there is record that is tied to user account then I would like to remove that record. I use session scope to store users ID's. Once user manually logs out or their session timed out this query should run. Here is example:

```
public void function onSessionEnd(required struct sessionScope, struct applicationScope={}) {
    local.qryTest = new Query();
    local.qryTest.setDatasource("#arguments.Application.dsnWriteDelete#");
    local.qryTest.setSQL("DELETE Locked WHERE RecID = :RecID");
    local.qryTest.addParam(name="RecID",value="#SESSION.userID#",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
    qryTest.execute();

    return; 
}
```

I use J2EE sessions in my application. Here is how I end my session when user logs out manually:

```
<cffunction name="LogOut" access="remote" output="yes" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfset local.fnResults = structNew()>

        <cfif structKeyExists(SESSION.AccountInfo, "AccountID")>
            <cftry>
                <cfset local.temp = getPageContext().getSession().invalidate()>
                <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "200"}>

                <cfcatch type="any">
                    <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "400", message : "Error! Please contact your administrator."}>
                </cfcatch>
            </cftry>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "400", message : "Error! Please contact your administrator."}>
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fnResults>
    </cffunction>
```

I'm not sure if onSessionEnd works any different with J2EE but code that I have above never deletes records from database table. I'm not sure if something is wrong in my code or this is not possible to achieve on session end.

Comment: In onSessionEnd, `session` isn't available.  You have to use the argument name instead - i.e. `arguments.sessionScope`

Comment: @Ageax I fixed that and if session times out query will be processed. However, if user logs out manually then `onSessionEnd` is not triggered. Do you know if it's possible to manually trigger `onSessionEnd` int hat case?

Comment: @espression_coffee - Technically yes, though I think it probably makes more sense to have the logout logic in a component and then call the appropriate method from both locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `session` scope isn't available inside [OnSessionEnd()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onsessionend.html). You must use the argument name instead, i.e. `arguments.sessionScope`

> However, if user logs out manually then onSessionEnd is not triggered. Do you know if it's possible to manually trigger onSessionEnd int [t]hat case?

Technically yes, though it probably makes more sense to place the logout logic in a component and then call the appropriate method from both locations (OnSessionEnd and manual logout script).